# use a list to specify which subdictionary to use

Tags: python

not sure how I want to go about this but essentially I have a list of items

```
section = ['messages','ProcQueueLen']
```

or

```
section = ['messages','CpuError']
```

...depending on what section we are in...

and some data points that belong in the procqueuelen section for instance.

I want to create a dynamic dictionary so I can add the data points (as dictionaries) to the correct dictionary entry.  So for instance:

```
<setup>
   logfile = cdm.log
   loglevel = 0
   cpu_usage_includes_wait = yes
   internal_alarm_message = InternalAlarm
   mem_buffer_used = no
   alarm_on_each_sample = no
   qos_source_short = yes
   trendsubject = cdm
   trendpriority = information  
   paging_in_kilobytes = yes
   post_install = 1382462705
   allow_qos_source_as_target = no
   monitor_iostat = yes
   allow_remote_disk_info = yes
</setup>
<messages>
   <ProcQueueLen>
      text = Average ($value_number samples) 
processor queue length is $value$unit, which is >= $value_limit$unit. Last value is $value_last$unit.
      level = minor
      token = proc_q_len
   </ProcQueueLen>
   <CpuError>
      text = Average ($value_number samples) total cpu is now $value$unit, which is above the error threshold ($value_limit$unit)
      level = major
      token = cpu_error
      i18n_token = as#system.cdm.avrg_total_cpu_above_err_threshold
   </CpuError>
</messages>
```

would yield a nested dictionary like the following:

```
conf = {'messages':{'ProcQueueLen':{'text':'Average ($value_number samples) processor queue length is $value$unit, which is >= $value_limit$unit. Last value is $value_last$unit.','level':'minor','token':'proc_q_len'},'CpuError':{'text':'Average ($value_number samples) total cpu is now $value$unit, which is above the error threshold ($value_limit$unit)','level':'major','token':'cpu_error','i18n_token':'as#system.cdm.avrg_total_cpu_above_err_threshold'}}}
```

I am reading a file with these different sections line by line and setting up what section the entries go in by appending and popping section as needed.  But I am not sure how to specify the nested dictionary based on this section list.

This is not valid xml as it is does not have correct sections and has invalid characters.  I have tried beautifulsoup but it is very slow.  It would be faster and easier for me to navigate by putting the data in a nested dictionary.

The only code I have at the moment is the following:

```
conf = {}
section = []
for i, line in enumerate(out.split('\\n')):
    l = line.strip()
    if i < 20:
        print(l)
        if l.startswith('</'):
            print('skipping')
        elif l.startswith('<'):
            conf[l] = {}
            section.append(l)
            print('create dbentry')
        else:
            conf[section][l.split('=')[0].strip()] = l.split('=')[1].strip()
            print('add to dbentry')
```

This is not working as [section] in this case would need to be a list of sections, and am not sure how to do that.

@Ajax1234 this is what i'm getting with your solution.

```
print([c for c in _r if c[0]])
[['\\n   logfile', 'cdm.log\\n   loglevel', '0\\n   cpu_usage_includes_wait', 'yes\\n   internal_alarm_message', 'InternalAlarm\\n   mem_buffer_used', 'no\\n   alarm_on_each_sample', 'no\\n   qos_source_short', 'yes\\n   trendsubject', 'cdm\\n   trendpriority', 'information\\n   paging_in_kilobytes', 'yes\\n   post_install', '1382462705\\n   allow_qos_source_as_target', 'no\\n   monitor_iostat', 'yes\\n   allow_remote_disk_info', 'yes\\n']]
print(dict([c for c in _r if c[0]]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 15; 2 is required
```

Comment: Can you show your code for us to start with?

Comment: If you can rely on the indentation of the text then just use that one to solve the nesting.

Comment: Is the question how to serialize a dict? You could write valid json or xml. Then you'd be able to read it as json or xml.

Comment: ***This is not working as [section] in this case would need to be a list of sections, and am not sure how to do that.***

Are you saying that either `CpuError` or `ProcQueueLen` can have multiple entries like:

`conf = {'messages':{'ProcQueueLen':[{'text':'bla','level':'minor','token':'t'},
{'text':'bla2','level':'minor','token':'t2'}, {'text':'bla3','level':'minor','token':'t3'}]}}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can redefine your input syntax, I'd recommend using normal .ini files and using Python's configparser.

I like Ajax's and Serge Ballista's answers, but if you want to modify your existing code to work, try this:

```
import pprint
conf = {}
section = []
for i, line in enumerate(out.split('\n')):
    l = line.strip()
    if i < 20:
        l = l.strip("\n")
        if not l:
            # skip if end of file
            continue 
        if l.startswith('</'):
            # we need to remove this from the list of current sections
            section.pop()
            print('skipping')
        elif l.startswith('<'):
            sec_name = l.strip("<>")  # what you wanted was conf["messages"], not conf["<messages>"]
            secstr = "".join(f"['{x}']" for x in section)  # create a string that looks something like ['messages']['ProcQueueLen']
            correct = eval(f"conf{secstr}")  # use the string to evaluate to an actual section in your conf dict          
            correct[sec_name] = {}  # set the new section to an empty dictionary
            section.append(sec_name)  # add the new section to the dictionary route
            print(f"create dbentry: {secstr}['{sec_name}']")
        else:
            secstr = "".join(f"['{x}']" for x in section)
            correct = eval(f"conf{secstr}")
            # you have = in the middle of config values, which means that you can't split on '=', but you can split on ' = ' if your format is consistent. 
            correct[l.split(' = ')[0].strip()] = l.split(' = ')[1].strip()
            print(f"add to dbentry: {correct[l.split(' = ')[0].strip()]}")
pprint.pprint(conf)
```

With this, and your input, I get the following output:

```
{'messages': {'CpuError': {'i18n_token': 'as#system.cdm.avrg_total_cpu_above_err_threshold',
                           'level': 'major',
                           'text': 'Average ($value_number samples) total cpu '
                                   'is now $value$unit, which is above the '
                                   'error threshold ($value_limit$unit)',
                           'token': 'cpu_error'},
              'ProcQueueLen': {'level': 'minor',
                               'text': 'Average ($value_number samples) '
                                       'processor queue length is $value$unit, '
                                       'which is >= $value_limit$unit. Last '
                                       'value is $value_last$unit.',
                               'token': 'proc_q_len'}}}
```

Comment: This worked for me,  the input was pretty dodgy so the other solutions did not work correctly,  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no arbitrary line breaks, you can use recursion with `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re, collections, functools
def parse(d):
  _d = collections.defaultdict(dict)
  for i in getattr(d, 'contents', []):
     if isinstance(i, str) and i != '\n':
        _r = [re.split('\s\=\s', c) for c in re.split('\n\s+', i)]
        _d[d.name].update(dict([c for c in _r if c[0]]))
     else:
        _d[d.name].update(parse(i))
  return _d
```

---

```
import json
result = functools.reduce(lambda x, y:{**x, **y}, [dict(parse(i)) for i in soup(data, 'html.parser').contents if not isinstance(i, str)])
print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
 "setup": {
    "logfile": "cdm.log",
    "loglevel": "0",
    "cpu_usage_includes_wait": "yes",
    "internal_alarm_message": "InternalAlarm",
    "mem_buffer_used": "no",
    "alarm_on_each_sample": "no",
    "qos_source_short": "yes",
    "trendsubject": "cdm",
    "trendpriority": "information  ",
    "paging_in_kilobytes": "yes",
    "post_install": "1382462705",
    "allow_qos_source_as_target": "no",
    "monitor_iostat": "yes",
    "allow_remote_disk_info": "yes\n"
},
"messages": {
    "procqueuelen": {
        "text": "Average ($value_number samples) processor queue length is $value$unit, which is >= $value_limit$unit. Last value is $value_last$unit.",
        "level": "minor",
        "token": "proc_q_len"
    },
    "cpuerror": {
        "text": "Average ($value_number samples) total cpu is now $value$unit, which is above the error threshold ($value_limit$unit)",
        "level": "major",
        "token": "cpu_error",
        "i18n_token": "as#system.cdm.avrg_total_cpu_above_err_threshold"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: getting the following error..."ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 15; 2 is required" for the line "_d[d.name].update(dict([c for c in _r if c[0]]))" .  I will update the question with a more detailed part of the text in question.  The input is very large so its hard to get all the important stuff.

Comment: @user1601716 Please post the input that raises that error.

Comment: I modified the example input that i believe is causing the error.

Comment: still failing at the same step.  Please see the update in the main section

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194458/discussion-between-user1601716-and-ajax1234).

Answer (score 0):

The example text can be parsed with `xml.etree` and the `re` module, provide the following assumptions are verified:

- an xml element can contain either other xml elements or text but not both
- continuation lines are not indented
- tag name in xml element contain valid characters

Code could be:

```
def process_text(t):
    def process_elt(elt, dic):             # process the XML part
        dic[elt.tag] = {}
        dic = dic[elt.tag]
        children = elt.getchildren()
        if len(children) > 0:
            for child in children:
                process_elt(child, dic)
        else:
            process_txt(elt.text, dic)

    def process_txt(t, dic):                   # process the textual part
        blank = re.compile(r'\s+')
        eq = re.compile(r'\s*([^=]*?)\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*$')
        old = None
        for line in io.StringIO(t):
            # continuation line are not indented
            if not blank.match(line) and old is not None:
                dic[old] += ' ' + line
            elif line.strip() != '':      # skip empty line
                m = eq.match(line)
                if m is None:
                    print('ERROR', line)
                old = m.group(1)
                dic[old] = m.group(2)

    conf = {}
    root = ET.fromstring(t)
    process_elt(root, conf)
    return conf
```

with your exact input text, I obtain:

```
{'messages': {'ProcQueueLen': {'text': 'Average ($value_number samples) processor queue length is $value$unit, which is >= $value_limit$unit. Last value is $value_last$unit.\n', 'level': 'minor', 'token': 'proc_q_len'}, 'CpuError': {'text': 'Average ($value_number samples) total cpu is now $value$unit, which is above the error threshold ($value_limit$unit)', 'level': 'major', 'token': 'cpu_error', 'i18n_token': 'as#system.cdm.avrg_total_cpu_above_err_threshold'}}}
```